# Pixi.js keeps accelerating on page refresh

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

These are my references created in pixi.js here:
http://brekalo.info/en/reference

If we go to references it loads pixiJS and everything works fine on first load! Then, if we go to another page let's say: http://brekalo.info/en/contact, and the go back to references again - now my references have accelerated text movement and rotation and it keeps accelerate on each reference page load!

Here is my javascript/pixi code below:

```
function initiatePixi() {

Object.keys(PIXI.utils.TextureCache).forEach(function(texture) {
    PIXI.utils.TextureCache[texture].destroy(true);}
);

// create an new instance of a pixi stage
var container = new PIXI.Container();

// create a renderer instance.
renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(frameWidth, frameHeight, transparent = false, antialias = true);

// set renderer frame background color
renderer.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;

// add the renderer view element to the DOM
document.getElementById('pixi-frame').appendChild(renderer.view);

// create references
createReferences(animate); // callback to animate frame

function createReferences(callback) {

    // Create text container
    textContainer = new PIXI.Container();
    textContainer.x = 0;
    textContainer.y = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < references.length; i++) {

        var style = {
            font:"22px Verdana",
            fill:getRandomColor()
        };

        var text = new PIXI.Text(references[i], style);

        text.x = getRandomInteger(20, 440); // text position x
        text.y = getRandomInteger(20, 440); // text position y

        text.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5); // set text anchor point to the center of text

        text.rotation = getRandomInteger(0, rotationLockDeg) * 0.0174532925; // set text rotation

        // make the text interactive
        text.interactive = true;

        // create urls on text click
        text.on("click", function (e) {
            var win = window.open("http://" + this.text, '_blank');
            win.focus();
        });

        textContainer.addChild(text);

        rotateText(); // rotate text each second

    }

    container.addChild(textContainer);

    // callback
    if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
        callback();
    }

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // render the stage
    renderer.render(container);
}

function rotateText() {

var rotateTimer = setInterval(function () {

    for (var key in textContainer.children) { // loop each text object

        var text = textContainer.children[key];

        if(text.rotation / 0.0174532925 < -rotationLockDeg || text.rotation / 0.0174532925 > rotationLockDeg) {

            if(text.rotation / 0.0174532925 < -rotationLockDeg)
                text.rotation = -rotationLockRad;
            if(text.rotation / 0.0174532925 > rotationLockDeg)
                text.rotation = rotationLockRad;

            rotation = -rotation;

        }

        text.rotation += rotation; // rotate text by rotate speed in degree

        if(text.x < 0 || text.x > 460)
            dx = -dx;
        if(text.y < 0 || text.y > 460)
            dy = -dy;

        text.x += dx;
        text.y += dy;
    }

}, 75);

}

// get random integer between given range (eg 1-10)
function getRandomInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// random hex color generator
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

:: cheers ::

Josip

Comment: Well, you call the `initiatePixi` function every time the References tab is loaded. You should only call the `animate` function **ONCE**. You call it multiple times, thus the update loop is executed more times per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Cristy thanks for the advice!

Here is how I manage to solve this..

I put one property in my pixi-parameters.js:

```
pixiWasLoaded = false;
```

Then, when I call initiatePixi() function, I set:

```
pixiWasLoaded = true;
```

Now in my controllers.js I have this piece of code:

```
.run( function($rootScope, $location, $window) {
    $rootScope.$watch(function() {
            return $location.path();
        },
        function(page){
            if(page == "/hr/reference" || page == "/en/references"){
                if($window.pixiWasLoaded)
                    $window.addRendererElementToDOM();
                else
                    loadReferences();
            }
        });
});
```

It checks if references page is loaded and then uses $window to find my global variable "pixiWasLoaded" and if it's not loaded then it loads PixiJS using loadReferences() function.. and if is already loaded it calls my part of code to add render-view to DOM so my animate function can render it..

:: cheers ::

Josip

Answer (score 1):

To expand [@Cristy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410526/pixi-js-keeps-accelerating-on-page-refresh#comment64819645_38410526) to an answer:

The answer lies in the same reason as why your question title is wrong: There is indeed *NO page refresh* when doing what you describe. If there were, you wouldn't have that problem in the first place. Try it out, hit `F5` a few times on you animated page, it will stay the same speed.

The reason is that you are running a angular based single page application, and only exchange the loaded view content on a route change. This does not stop your already running animation code from continuing to run in the background while you navigate to another view, so that when you return to the animated tab you will create another set of interval timers for your animation, which will result in more executions and thus a visually faster animation.

Comment: So, to fix this issue, I need to check if PixiJS was already loaded and prevent calling animate function again? Thx